# Can a gap between toes be caused by something other than "plantar plate tear"?

Tags: feet

Many web sites talk about treatment for a painful injury, whose primary symptom is a gap forming between two toes:

> Have you noticed that two of your toes have come out of line? Perhaps where they used to line up normally alongside one another, they’re now moving apart from one another like a ‘V’.
> This is actually something we refer to as the ‘V Sign’, and more often than not, it’s linked to a plantar plate injury at the ball of your foot.
> …
> Generally, those with an injury to the plantar plate experience pain and tenderness at the ball of the foot in the affected regions.
> There may be some swelling and the feeling that you’re walking directly on the bone.
> Because the plantar plate ligament is damaged, it won’t be able to maintain the usual alignment at the ball of the foot, and the toes may drift apart, creating that ‘V’ sign.
> — [Toes Separating like a ‘V’? It’s a Sign of a Plantar Plate Tear](https://www.performpodiatry.co.nz/toes-separating-plantat-plate-tear/),

> This is a serious injury to the ball of the foot that often gets confused for other conditions—particularly neuromas.
> As a result, plantar plate tears can easily become more painful and severe without effective treatment.
> Untreated plantar plate tears can even lead to hammertoes, arthritis, and other painful long-term problems.
>
> If you’ve noticed pain in the ball of your foot and your second toe “popping up” or drifting out of alignment, give us a call.
> You may be suffering from this condition—and you need an accurate diagnosis so you can get the relief you deserve.
> — [Treatment for Plantar Plate Tear | Austin Foot and Ankle Specialists](https://www.austinfootandankle.com/practice_areas/treatment-for-plantar-plate-tear.cfm#:%7E:text=As%20a%20result%2C%20plantar%20plate,other%20painful%20long%2Dterm%20problems.)

But what if one has the "V" symptom, but:

- There is no pain.
- Both feet have developed the same gap between the second and third toes.

Simultaneous identical injuries to both feet seems unlikely, especially without any pain.

Are there other causes for this phenomenon?

Comment: If it's always been there, it's genetic. If it developed almost unnoticed over years, it's due to wear and tear on your feet (due to whatever: overpronation, hypermobility, whatever). Plantar Plate injuries hurt. Looking at my feet now, I notice a significant V-shaped separation between my third and fourth toes bilaterally, but greater on the left. My very unprofessional opinion for my deformity (and this is coming from a professional) is to totally ignore it. Maybe someday it will hurt, but it doesn't now.